# Piped I/O stream in java

Tags: java

I am not able to understand the purpose of piped i/o streams in java. If I write something using an outputstream, I can anyways read it again using an inputstream.

So what is the need of a pipedstream?

Comment: Start by reading the javadoc.

Comment: Could not really get something beneficial from the javadoc. It simply says how to use it not why we are using it.

Comment: `the piped input stream then provides whatever data bytes are written to the piped output stream.` You get them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short motivation:

1. **Separation of concerns** (always good - in this case it helps split your code into reading and writing part)
2. Multithreading (previous point lead to "easy" (its never easy :D) parallelization)

Long explanation/example:

Imagine you have "producer-consumer" like application. You have one part of your code that generates output and you want provide it with place to where write data to. For example:

```
void generateLines(int numberOfLines, OutputStream target);
```

There is only single responsibility of this component i.e. it "produces" lines and it doesnt know where the lines are written to. You just call it like `generateLines(5, System.out)` or `generateLines(100, fileOutputStream)`. But imagine you want to assemble "pipeline" i.e. you do not want to store/print the data but instead you want to pass them to another component "consumer".

You could have component with signature like that:

```
int countLines(InputStream source);
```

Only thing this does is it reads data from `InputStream` which is provided externally.

Now thanks to "Piped" streams you can glue those two component together by creating "pipe" like:

```
PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(pos, 1024);
```

Then you can run two threads, one that generates data and another that consumes them. Pipe api is really convenient, reading/writing is blocking (see javadoc for more details) so the usage is really simple/convenient.

```
// Withing main thread start generating of x lines into pos OutputStream
generateLines(50000, pos);
// Spawn new thread within which we consume pipe from its InputStream end
Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
   pis.read();
   // The rest of "reading-loop" omitted for sake of simplicity...
});
```

Of course this example is dummy but one can easily imagine use cases like "generating huge xml" (produce) into writable stream and "compressing/validating" (consume) it and so on.

Maybe there is better example but personally I use those pipes for producer-consumer jobs as described before.

Answer (score 3):

**Pipes** in **Java IO** provides the ability for two threads running in the same JVM to communicate. As such pipes are a common source or destination of data.

A `PipedInputStream` should be connected to a `PipedOutputStream`. The data written to the `PipedOutputStream` by one thread, can thus be read from the connected `PipedInputStream` by another thread

Normal Java IO does not support streaming to the same stream from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I think its supposed to be for reading and writing in a multi-threaded application. Where you can write in a thread and read in the other one, without flushing the data.