# read line from sequence of byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays, bluetooth-lowenergy, byte

I receive data from Bluetooth BLE as follow in 250 bytes chunk at most.

```
onDataReceived(byte[] data) {
  my_readline();  // <-- how could I implement this
}
```

the data are string but chuncked. so what is the proper way to detect lines from incomming byte arrays. or it would be good as well if it is possible to convert received data to inputStream as well.

Comment: It is possible with java's **piped I/O** utilising two threads. Found something related in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348320/piped-i-o-stream-in-java . Synchronized would for an InputStream block onDataReceived which is wrong. One would need polling (isAvailable).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert byte array to String,

```
String inputStr = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

And if you want to convert to InputStream,

```
InputStream dataInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
```

Comment: how to read line from inputStr and how it is possible to add new byte arrays to inputStr

Comment: If you want to add new bytes, you could use StringBuilder and append the strings. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an ByteArrayInputStream and turn that into an BufferedReader. It is not very clean altough it should work.

```
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Comment: how to add continusly comming data byte arrays to ByteArrayInputStream?

Comment: that is not an possibility for as far as I know. You can only process the data once you have it all together